# JavaScript - Image Paths

Tags: javascript, image, http, url

I have the following JavaScript/HTML code:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <script src="Resources/jQuery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function change_image()
        {
            var url = document.getElementById('Change_Image').src;

            if (url == 'http://placehold.it/200x200')
            {
                document.getElementById('Change_Image').src = 'http://placehold.it/100x100';
            }

            else
            {
                document.getElementById('Change_Image').src = 'http://placehold.it/200x200';
            }
        }

        setInterval(change_image, 1000);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <h1>Welcome to my Website</h1>
            <h2>Below you can find an example of visual cryptography</h2>
            <br />
            <br />
            <div><img id="Change_Image" src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="Letter A"/></div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The code switches between two images every two seconds.  The images are stored online.

Now, in my project, I have a folder called Resources, containing two images called Share1.bmp and Share2.bmp.

If I modify the code above to use these two images, nothing works anymore.  This is how I am doing it:

```
if (url == '../Resources/Share1.bmp')
            {
                document.getElementById('Change_Image').src = '../Resources/Share2.bmp';
            }

            else
            {
                document.getElementById('Change_Image').src = '../Resources/Share1.bmp';
            }

...
...
<div><img id="Change_Image" src="../Resources/Share1.bmp" alt="Letter A"/></div>
```

What am I doing wrong?  Am I passing the url to the images stored in my project incorrectly?

**EDIT**

When using my images, Share1.bmp is displayed correctly, however the switching does not occur.  It seems that the problem is with the URLs in the JavaScript.

Comment: >>What am I doing wrong?


You're not using jquery toggle as I've suggested in the other post :-)

Comment: @HMR When using the online images, the program works perfectly though.  It's when I use the images stored on my computer that the problem arises.

Comment: You can get funny values using img.src. why not try Firefox with firebug or chrome and console.log(img.src) before comaring. I still think using jquery is easier and cleaner. if you want it every 2 seconds I can post the code here.

Comment: img.src always gives the full path. Try checking with full path in your conditions e.g. if(url === "http://<host>/Resources/Share1.bmp"). Or check for src ending with the value you want.

Comment: @HMR - Matthew did not say anything about jQuery in the question!

Comment: It's a re post of another question. He's using .net C#. Maybe MVC raisor that uses jQuery for form validation so it's in there anyway. The code posted has a reference to jQuery.js as well

Comment: @HMR Good spot on the jQuery script (I was looking at tags) and that it's a follow on from a previous quwstion. Matthew please, if possible link related questions together in future - just include a URL to your other question and SO will turn it into a nice link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery you can just put both images there and have them hide show (toggle).

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

your html:

```
<div class="someContainer">
 <img class="Change_Image" src="Resources/Share1.bmp" alt="Letter A" />
 <img class="Change_Image" src="Resources/Share2.bmp" alt="Letter B" 
   style="display:none"/>
</div>
```

your javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var toggleImages=function(){
    $(".someContainer").find(".Change_Image").toggle();
    setTimeout(toggleImages,2000);
  }
  toggleImages();
});
```

To write your own implementation of toggle (works only for this particular instance) you can add this JS directly after the div containing your images:

```
<div class="someContainer" id="myImageContainer">
 <img src="Resources/Share1.bmp" alt="Letter A" />
 <img src="Resources/Share2.bmp" alt="Letter B" 
   style="display:none"/>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
 (function(){
   var images= document.getElementById("someContainer")
     .getElementsByTagName("img")
   ,toggleImages=function(){
     for(var i = 0;i < images.length;i++){
       images[i].style.display=(image.style.display==="none")?
         "":"none";
     }
     setTimeout(toggleImages,2000);
   };
   toggleImages();
 })();
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks HMR :)  I should have tried your solution in the first place :)

Comment: If you don't mind the overhead of a JavaScript library for functionality that can be written in JavaScript that is!

Comment: jQuery comes with many .net templates. It has auto-complete in Visual Studio. I agree that it might load a library that you don't use for 90% but it's smaller than a banner image. If you're worried to have too much code you can use closure library and closure compiler (advanced) but that has a steep learning curve.

Comment: OK, missed that jQuery was already included. `+1` for comprehensive answer

Comment: OK, missed that jQuery was already included. `+1` for comprehensive answer

Answer (score 0):

The issue is more than likely the relative path to the images.  Try changing the path to (remove the ../):

/Resources/Share2.bmp and /Resources/Share1.bmp